# Django views not render data after user submit form

Tags: python, django

It sound simple but I want my page to display the database of my model.

I use ModelForm for user to input and it would save into my model. Now I want to render the whole table, not just each separately.

forms.py

```
class My_Folio(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = my_data
        fields = ['symbol','buy_price','quantity']
```

views.py

```
def blockfolio(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_folio = My_Folio(request.POST)
        if my_folio.is_valid():
            symbol = my_folio.cleaned_data['symbol']
            buy_price =  my_folio.cleaned_data['buy_price']
            quantity =  my_folio.cleaned_data['quantity']
            instance = my_folio.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return render(request, 'blockfolio/blockfolio.html', {'symbol':symbol, 'buy_price':buy_price, 'quantity':quantity, 'instance':instance})
```

template:

`{{instance}}` This give me the user input after submit, but I want to show all of the inputs saved in database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your post is invalid. Try this code in `views.py`.

```
def blockfolio(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_folio = My_Folio(request.POST)
        if my_folio.is_valid():
            symbol = my_folio.cleaned_data['symbol']
            buy_price =  my_folio.cleaned_data['buy_price']
            quantity =  my_folio.cleaned_data['quantity']
            instance = my_folio.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return render(request, 'blockfolio/blockfolio.html', {'symbol':symbol, 'buy_price':buy_price, 'quantity':quantity, 'instance':instance}) 
        else:
            print("request is invalid: {}".format(request.POST))
            return "bad request!", 500
```

Comment: No errors here after adding this. But what I meant to ask is once my form input goes back into my model, I want to show the whole table of inputs on my page. Not each individual input. Right now, this part render each input after submit.What to put so model `my_data` render?
 

    `{'symbol':symbol, 'buy_price':buy_price, 'quantity':quantity,'instance':instance})`